# Loading help documentation alters irb results

Tags: ruby, initialization, irb

I'm learning Ruby, and went into irb to test something out with the Date class. In short, I did the following:

```
$ irb 
irb(main):001:0> Date.new 
=> #<Date:0x007f983103ee60> 
irb(main):002:0> Date.constants 
=> [] 
irb(main):003:0> help Date 
=> nil 
irb(main):004:0> Date.constants 
=> [:MONTHNAMES, :ABBR_MONTHNAMES, :DAYNAMES, :ABBR_DAYNAMES, :ITALY, :ENGLAND, :JULIAN, :GREGORIAN, :Infinity] 
irb(main):005:0>
```

I'm so confused by this. Questions:

- Why would reading help documentation cause the output of `Date.constants` to change?
- Presumably `help` is loading/initializing something. What is it? And why did `Date.new` work?
- Is whatever this is something I need to worry about when writing .rb files?

This is tough to Google for. I'm on ruby 2.1.2 and irb 0.9.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of the addition of the `Date` constants after running `help Date` is that somewhere in the execution of the command, `require 'date'` (or `require 'time'`) is called:

```
2.1.0 :001 > Date.constants
 => [] 
2.1.0 :002 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.1.0 :003 > Date.constants
 => [:MONTHNAMES, :ABBR_MONTHNAMES, :DAYNAMES, :ABBR_DAYNAMES, :ITALY, :ENGLAND, :JULIAN, :GREGORIAN, :Infinity]
```

As for `Date.new`, it works because `Date` comes with a default constructor.

I doubt this will ever be problematic for you.